# Not able to install python-dev because of dependencies on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, python, aptitude

How can I resolve this problem (without damaging my computer!)? I want to  install `python-dev` on my Ubuntu. I already tried `aptitude`, it wasn't helpful.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libexpat1-dev libpython-dev libpython2.7-dev python-dev  

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libexpat1-dev : Depends: libexpat1 (= 2.1.0-7) but 2.1.0-7ubuntu0.16.04.2 is to be installed
 libpython2.7-dev : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.11-7ubuntu1) but 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libpython2.7 (= 2.7.11-7ubuntu1) but 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1 is to be installed
 python-dev : Depends: python2.7-dev (>= 2.7.11-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

Extra:

```
$ apt policy libexpat1-dev
libexpat1-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.1.0-7
  Version table:
     2.1.0-7 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
$ grep "^deb " /etc/apt/sources.li
st
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
$ apt policy python2.7-dev
python2.7-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.7.11-7ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.7.11-7ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Do you have any PPA enabled? are your source up to date?

Comment: @Ravexina Yes. PPAs are enabled and the packages are up to date.

Comment: What is the output of `apt policy libexpat1-dev` and `grep "^deb " /etc/apt/sources.list` add it to your question, also `apt policy python2.7-dev`.

Comment: @Ravexina Question edited.

Comment: Add this line: `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main universe multiverse` to `/etc/apt/sources.list` then run `sudo apt update` after that check see if you can install it, if it worked I'll send it as an answer.

Comment: @Ravexina It definitely did!  Also helped to install other packages that I've not been able to install. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome, I sent it as answer, ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems you don't have an important repository in your `sources.list` enabled.

Add this line:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main universe multiverse
```

to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then use `sudo apt update`.

it should do the trick.